# Highlight <li> in function onClick in js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a little issue.

I want to highlight the answer when you click on it but the `.style` seem not working :(

I have a part of html code like this:

```
<div id="answers-type1">
    <ol>
        <img src="" id="answer-a-img" /><li id="answer-a" ></li>
        <img src="" id="answer-b-img" /><li id="answer-b" ></li>
        <img src="" id="answer-c-img" /><li id="answer-c" ></li>
        <img src="" id="answer-d-img" /><li id="answer-d" ></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

and in my script i got this:

```
$("#answers-type1 li").click(function() {
     $(this).style = "background-color: #FFFF00;";
     if ($(this).text() == goodAnswer)
     {
         alert("JAYJAY");
     }
     else
     {
         alert("pas JAYJAY");
     }
});
```

the function is well called on each click but the background is not changing i don't understand why :/

I looked over internet and saw a lot of people doing like that

thanks for answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
$(this).css("background-color","#FFFF00");
```

instead of this

```
this.style = "background-color: #FFFF00;";
```

Answer (score 2):

The style is not applied because jQuery objects don't have a `style` property. You can use the `css` method instead:

```
$(this).css("background-color","#FFFF00");
```

Alternatively, you could use the underlying element (don't pass it to jQuery):

```
this.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFF00";
```

The second example will likely be more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed here: http://jsfiddle.net/RichardTowers/99Zpz/

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$(this).css("background-color","#FFFF00");
```

instead of :

```
$(this).style = "background-color: #FFFF00;";
```